# Why does focus() not work the way it seems like it should?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="../js/third_party/jq142unmin.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function(){
            $("#set_focus1").click(function(){
                console.log($("#input1").focus());
            });
            $("#set_focus2").click(function(){
                console.log($("#input2").focus());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="input1"></input>
    <input id="input2"></input>
    <button id="set_focus1">Set Focus1</button>
    <button id="set_focus2">Set Focus2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

The code itself works like I think it should, eg., clicking the buttons sets focus on one input or the other. But if I try the same thing from a console, it has no effect (no error messages, just doesn't do anything). I tried it a couple of different ways, as shown above.

Other jQuery functions executed from the console on these input elements, eg. $("#input1").val("foo"), works like I would expect. What's different about focus()?

Comment: So the code works as it should as in setting the focus but when you run it from the console it does nothing?  What is it you are trying to do?  .focus() works - as you stated earlier

Comment: The focus stays on the console when you are typing in it. It can't move to the browser window. The javascript code can only move the focus from one part of the browser window to another.

Comment: Question should be "why xxx is not working in console". Answer is: don't bother

Comment: I'm actually trying to figure out why some framework code we have to set focus doesn't work; the maze of code involved is too much to post here, and the console thing was part of my exploration of how focus works. Thanks for the feedback, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reproduced this, and it's not an error, it's simply how the browser processes your input. While you're in your developer tools, the page doesn't have your reticle, and therefore isn't passing it to another element.

The element does in fact get "focused." Run this in your browser, and you'll see that the `focus()` event does fire, but with your attention on another window, the browser isn't going to force-change you to that page.

```
$("#input1").on("focus", function(){  alert("focused")  });
$("#input1").focus();
```

This will trigger an alert.

Comment: That's a good explanation and suggestion, thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Console is separate from the browser window. So when you execute some commands in the console, the focus will not move to the the html window. That is why you are not getting the expected result.

`$("#input1").val("foo")` is setting the value of a DOM element. So it will change the value and keep the cursor in the console.

To validate `$("#input1").focus()` you could put an alert in the focus event and then call the event from the console.